# Convert a tuple of bytes into a string in python?

Tags: string, tuples, byte, aes, rsa

I have this code

```
subject1 = pubkey.encrypt(aeskey, 32) # tuple of bytes
str(subject1)
```

this returns

```
#(b'5\xec*\x97U\x0f,wKI\xbd@\xe1\xf0\xf7}\xf9=(\xfb\x1e@;\x18\xe8X\xbe\x96u\\\xdd\x90\x1c\xc4T\xdc\xa6\xf6e\x81?z9C\xc0\x10M\x99e~s[]L\x98^D\x8f\xb2)\xbf\t)\x96\xc3-\xf5y\xb7\xe1\x93\xb8\xd3\x19\xa6\xef\xc8\xa7\x8fx\xdc\x8f\xaa\xa1;\xeb\xc1\\\x01\n,\xe1\x8d\x8a\xe4\xa4\xcb$\x0e\xe9\xcf\x1fW\xe4\xeb\xb0&\xf2\x975\x98\xbd\xcdc+\x8d\x11\xbb\xdd\xf3__s.\x98\x168\xcc',)
```

whereas it should return a string without without the 'b' in the starting something like this

```
('C&O\x08\xa2\xf8eLJ\xc4LG|\xd6"\xd10\xa8T\x9c\xcfT\x1a\xdf\xad\xa5\xca\xaf\xea\x0e4\xa0\xc1\xfd\xe7\xbb\xbb1p\x03\x96-d\x8d\xefAv\x85\xd5\x01\xdb\x9e\x13A\xedo\xa4\x8b\xbe\xdf;\x90-\xf5\xd9\xcf@\xddK\xaa\x8f;R\xff\xb9Z\xf0\xe0,\x07\x8b\xe2\xe6%\xd2\xf0\xc6\x0c3\x10\xa9H\xdbG\xa0\xac\xc4\xa2E\xc0\x82\\\xa6\x14xzQ|k\xb9\x9cb\x83\xe9\xaf[\'n:\xcdy\x9c8\x8f\xddB\xcd\xbc',)
```

the bytes are of RSA encrypted AES key

Comment: Trying to make it into a string makes no sense at all. It is a bytes object containing arbitrary byte sequences. Rethink what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JamesKPolk okay. I need to make a string out of a message which is encrypted by an AES key and the AES key needs to be encrypted with RSA and send this string as a message in the form of an email using SMTP library, how would you suggest to do it?

Comment: If you must send arbitrary bytes as a string, for example in email, it needs to be encoded. base64 encoding is fairly standard. The receiving end must base64 decode it before decrypting.